# Import Postgres data into Google Spreadsheets

Tags: postgresql, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I was trying to achieve this using google app script but sadly app script does not have a jdbc connector for postgres. Can someone please help me out with detailed steps on what needs to be done in order to get the postgres data in spreadsheets.

Comment: Google app script can only connect to  Google Cloud SQL, MySQL, Microsoft SQL Server, and Oracle databases.

Comment: And as per this link https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=415, I don't think this feature will be supported any time soon in the future

Answer (score 0):

If you go to [JDBC Apps Script guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc) it says there that:

> "Apps Script can connect to external databases through the JDBC
>   service, a wrapper around the standard Java Database Connectivity
>   technology. In Apps Script, the JDBC service supports Google Cloud
>   SQL, MySQL, Microsoft SQL Server, and Oracle databases."

No mention of PostgeSQL support as of now.